# How can I avoid Streaming API Limits Developer Edition

Tags: apex, streaming-api

I'm using Salesforce Streaming API to handle agent status in a Call Center application, every time the agent make a call or is answering one agent status is changing and as I'm suscribed to a push topic it is generating event.

I would like to know how to avoid the limits or the best practices to use Streaming API.

I checked Streaming API limits information in this link (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/Content/limits.htm) but maybe exist something that can give the best way to implement this approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the URL parameters to get the right data for each of your agents. So instead of creating a PushTopic for each person, you can use one master PushTopic that lives around the appropriate interface and parameterize the client subscriptions.

You can insert a PushTopic like:

```
insert new PushTopic(
    Name        = 'Doers',
    Query       = 'SELECT Id, Doer__c FROM Object1__c', //WHERE <snip>
    ApiVersion  = 29.0
);
```

**[Update:](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34826/streaming-api-mvel-operators/34913?noredirect=1#comment116530_34913)**

> basic filtering available in the form:
>
> ```
> /topic/MyTopic?User__c=005A0000000gqi6IAA
> ```
>
> Conditions can be combined by using an `&` for example:
>
> ```
> /topic/MyTopic?User__c=005A0000000gqi6IAA&Id={ID-18Char}
> ```
>
> This translates into OR condition: `User__c == 005A0000000gqi6IAA OR Id == {ID-18Char}`
>
> This is not nearly as robust as MVEL operations but can help reduce the number of received events

Comment: To all those having a buzz reading this answer and discovering this amazing feature: it has later been removed as per this comment http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/34913/12901 =)

Comment: Note: MVEL has been disabled but see my comment on the following post for basic filter operations. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34826/streaming-api-mvel-operators