# Getting Streaming (or alternative) to work for customer community user profiles

Tags: apex, customer-community, streaming-api

We want to enable `PushTopics` for customer community users. I see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33268/can-a-customer-community-user-access-pushtopics-for-streaming-api) that it was not possible. I also see that the external user licenses (customer and partner community) do not have access to the `PushTopic` object. What is the best work around to allow customer community users to listen to updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look into [Adding a Feed to Your Force.com Site](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/adding-a-feed-to-your-force-com-site). See also the **Syndication Feeds** section of [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites#Syndication_Feeds):

> Syndication feeds gives site visitors the ability to subscribe to changes within Force.com Sites and receive updates in external feed readers. First, enable the feed for your site by checking the "Enable Feeds" check box on site definition
>
> Create a feed entry by simply defining a SOQL query to retrieve the data that you want to appear in the feed, and by creating a mapping definition to map the data to the feed output. Here's an example SOQL query to retrieve three fields from the database object "account":
>
> ```
> select id, name, description from account
> ```
>
> Here is an accompanying mapping definition:
>
> ```
> ft: "My Feed", fa: "Jon Mountjoy", et: Name, ec: Description , el: "/" + Id, ect: "html"
> ```
>
> This maps the data to an Atom syndication feed format, and is described on the help page. In particular, `ft` stands for "feed title", ``fa`for "feed author",`et`for "entry title",`ec`for "entry description",`el` for "entry link" and so on. As you can see, the system automatically iterates over the result to generate the feed.
>
> You can create one or more syndication feeds for your organization's public sites or any Visualforce page.

**Pros**

- Licensing is not an issue.

**Cons**

- The feed is *public* and does not require any authentication.
- A `Syndication Feed` would take some creativity to tailor to specific `Account` record(s).